# Send paramater to URL.Action link in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a web app consuming a Web Api to retrieve a Product by Id. I am trying to make an update of this object using JQuery. So, sending as a paramater the id and then consume web api from controller and then passing the object to the view using razor:

> ```
> function UpdateProduct(id) {
>             jQuery.support.cors = true;
>             window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Update", "Product", new {id})";
>         }
> ```

Above code does not compile, shows error at new{id}. The purpose is send the id, and from update.cshtml view while loading the page, consuming the api and loading Product values into txtBoxes for update.

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public int Quantity { set; get; }
    }
```

How can achieve this using JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Url.Action works only in Razor Engine (I assume you work in .NET)

You can't use that method in Javascript.

But this should work

```
window.location.href = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/Product/Update/" + id;
```